# Pull latest Youtube Video from json url? (example url given)

Tags: php, wordpress, youtube, gdata

I am trying to automatically "add-new" Wordpress post when a Youtube User uploads a new video. Using wp_insert_post(); I can echo what I need to, but how do I write a function that determines: "If youtuber posts new video, then echo results, if else do not post"?

I have been using gdata.youtube.com to decode the json format with my queries, pulling and echoing the data into my theme.

Unfortunately I do not know how to proceed in grabbing the "latest video".

We will use "markiplierGame" as an example Youtuber to pull from.

Example URL: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/markiplierGame/uploads?max-results=50

```
// User inputs his Youtube ID in theme-options.
$youtuber = get_post_meta ($post->ID, 'youtuber_id', $single = true);

// The ID is then injected into the gdata variable.
$youtuber_gdata= file_get_contents("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/{$youtuber }/uploads?max-results=50");

// json data is then decoded.
$uploads = json_decode($youtuber_gdata);

// Grab the terms needed from decoded gdata
// "entry", "yt$statistics", and "viewCount" are examples of data I can pull.
$new_videos = $uploads->{'entry'}->{'yt$statistics'}->{'viewCount'};
```

Can anyone help me figure out how to grab the latest video from the json url? I need this to be accurate, or even be able to pull all previous uploads from a bigger youtube user.

Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: Cross-posted: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/150052

Comment: wonder why, because no one here bothers half the time.